# Using AndEngine with older build targets?

Tags: android, andengine, game-engine

Is it fine to use AndEngine with older build target to try to support as many users as possible?

EX. using build target 1.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer GLES2 version only goes back to 2.2+, the older GLES1 version will support 1.6+

Comment: another thing to consider is the current platform distribution - 1.6 is only 0.7% of the installed base

http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html